# linking ItemFileReadStore with FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
 var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({"url":"http://localhost:8080/Sai/samu"}); 
});
```

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" store="jsonStore"  required="true"   id="MyId" ></div>
```

**I am getting error stating as jsonStore not defined .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing [programmatic and declarative Dojo](http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-widget) approaches. You should use one or the other.

**Programmatic:**

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Sai/samu"
    });
    var filtSel = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect(
        {
            id: "MyId",
            store: jsonStore,
            required: true
        },
        "MyId" // Id of div to turn into filteringSelect  
    );
});
...
<div id="MyId"></div>
```

**Declarative**

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="jsonStore" url="http://localhost:8080/Sai/samu"></div>
<div dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" store="jsonStore" required="true"   id="MyId" ></div>
```